# Use ASCII for video chat in android

Tags: android, ascii, bandwidth, videochat

I want to build a video chat application which uses ASCII for video. I feel like this will use less internet bandwidth. It will be something like this but on Android. How will I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

ASCII is not a recommended codec to minimize bandwidth usage of video. Better have a look at [3gp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3GP_and_3G2) multimedia system which is used for mobile communications.